# Django exposes raw html on a rendered website

Tags: python, html, django

I am learning Django with the documentation tutorial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/

I have just completed the "Write views that actually do something" part, but somethings is definitely amiss. Even though I copied the code 1:1, this is the render I get:

[image: the render I get]

Last two bits of code I edited:

**index.html in polls/templates/polls directory**:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**views.py in polls directory:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

Comment: Why are you not using simply `return render(request,"polls/index.html", context)` in your `index` view? The example `loader.get_template` is only for learning purpose, while building real projects, we don't use it.

Comment: Well, as I said I am just learning and I stopped there since I got different results than the tutorial was saying.
Just going to finish it and try Mikhail's solution.
Thanks for contributing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your view to make it more simple:

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it after I finish the tutorial and there are no more changes to this document

Comment: @Swantewit Yes, the example of documentation for 7 basic tutorials is same from the years. That is used in django 1.8 or maybe 2.0.